Restricted root system for orthogonal group
The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} =  \mathfrak{so}(2,3)$ consists of $5 \times 5$ matrices $M$ satisfying
$$M^tB + BM=0$$
where $$B= \begin{pmatrix}  &  &  &  & 1 \\  &  &  & 1 &  \\  &  & 1 &  &  \\  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 1 &  &  &  &  \end{pmatrix}$$
Find the  the set of restricted roots and simple roots.
My attempt:
I have proved that $$\mathfrak{a} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 &  &  &  & \\  &  \lambda_2 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  &  -\lambda_2 &  \\  &  &  &  & -\lambda_1 \end{pmatrix} \mid \lambda_i \in \mathbb R\right\}$$ is a Cartan subalgebra. Hence dimension of $\mathfrak{a}$ is $2$.
Now let $(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2)$ be the standard basis for $\mathfrak{a}^*$, which means that
$$\left\langle \epsilon_i, \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 &  &  &  & \\  &  \lambda_2 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  &  -\lambda_2 &  \\  &  &  &  & -\lambda_1 \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle = \lambda_i,$$
for $i = 1,2$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: \mathfrak{a}^{*} \times \mathfrak{a} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the natural pairing. We denote $\Lambda$ be the set of restricted roots, i.e. $\alpha \in \mathfrak{a}^* \smallsetminus \{0\}$ such that
$$\mathfrak{g}_\alpha = \{z \in \mathfrak{g} \mid [a, z] = \langle \alpha, a\rangle z \ \text{for all}\ a \in \mathfrak{a\}}$$  is nonzero.
Now I cannot proceed further. Can anyone please help me to compute?

To make a restricted root system you should really choose a Cartan decomposition and find a maximal abelian subalgebra inside the split part (a.k.a the noncompact part). Fortunately your $\mathfrak{a}$ would fit into an appropriately chosen decomposition (you couldn't have chosen it to be diagonal if it wasn't in some split part). This is important as not all Cartan subalgebras are equivalent in a real Lie algebra.
Calculating the roots is just a matter of finding your root spaces. I will assume we know nothing to start with.
Firstly note that your Lie algebra as defined is given by matrices of the form:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & 0\\ a_{21} &  a_{22} & a_{23} & 0 & -a_{14} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & 0 & -a_{23} & -a_{13} \\ a_{41} & 0 & -a_{32} & -a_{22} & -a_{12} \\ 0 & -a_{41} & -a_{31} & -a_{21} & -a_{11} \end{pmatrix} $$
Then you can calculate for example
$$\left[\begin{pmatrix} 1 &  &  &  & \\  &  0 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  &  0 &  \\  &  &  &  & -1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & 0\\ a_{21} &  a_{22} & a_{23} & 0 & -a_{14} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & 0 & -a_{23} & -a_{13} \\ a_{41} & 0 & -a_{32} & -a_{22} & -a_{12} \\ 0 & -a_{41} & -a_{31} & -a_{21} & -a_{11} \end{pmatrix}\right] = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & 0\\ -a_{21} &  0 & 0 & 0 & -a_{14} \\ -a_{31} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_{13} \\ -a_{41} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_{12} \\ 0 & a_{41} & a_{31} & a_{21} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Similarly we have
$$\left[\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  &  &  & \\  &  1 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  & -1 &  \\  &  &  &  & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & 0\\ a_{21} &  a_{22} & a_{23} & 0 & -a_{14} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & 0 & -a_{23} & -a_{13} \\ a_{41} & 0 & -a_{32} & -a_{22} & -a_{12} \\ 0 & -a_{41} & -a_{31} & -a_{21} & -a_{11} \end{pmatrix}\right] = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -a_{12} & 0 & a_{14} & 0\\ a_{21} &  0 & a_{23} & 0 & -a_{14} \\ 0 & -a_{32} & 0 & -a_{23} & 0 \\ -a_{41} & 0 & a_{32} & 0 & a_{12} \\ 0 & -a_{41} & 0 & -a_{21} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Hopefully you can see, upon careful examination, that the root spaces are each of the form: $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a_{ij} &  \\  & \ddots & -a_{ij}   \\  &  &  0 \end{pmatrix}$$
as they are each eigenvectors for our diagonal matrices. You can then read off the roots as well since we have the eigenvalues for each of our diagonal matrices written there in the matrix.
If that calculation looks a bit intense (fair enough) you can try it on matrices with only 1 nonzero $a_{ij}$ but I wanted to have something you can read the whole root system off.
So, for example,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a &  &  & \\  &  0 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  & 0 & -a \\  &  &  &  & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
is a root vector with root $\epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2$ since it had an eigenvalue of $1$ for the first one but $-1$ for the second.
Likewise $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  & a &  & \\  &  0 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  & -a \\  &  &  & 0 &  \\  &  &  &  & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
is a root vector with root $\epsilon_1$ since it had an eigenvalue of $1$ for the first and $0$ for the second.
Running through all the possibilities we see we have all combinations of the form $\pm\epsilon_1 \pm \epsilon_2$ appearing exactly once and all ones of the form $\pm\epsilon_1$ and $\pm\epsilon_2$ appearing exactly once as well. This is just the $B_2$ root system.
Note this is the same as the normal root system of $\mathfrak{so}(5,\mathbb{C})$. This is because $\mathfrak{so}(3,2)$ is the split real form.

Thank you very much for your kind and detailed answer. I am have added an answer that I have understood from your answer. Am I correct?
